# undefined reference to variable i

Tags: c

here is my piece of code

```
#include<stdio.h>
 main ()
{
        extern int i;
        i=20;
     printf("%d",i);
}
```

When I compile it I get error

```
ka2.c: In function ‘main’:
ka2.c:6: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’
/tmp/ccGXrSE5.o: In function `main':
**ka2.c:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `i'**
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I want to know the reason of error in lines which I have bolded.

Comment: What do you think that `extern` means?

Comment: The warning does not match the code. -1 for fake code.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler what compiler did you used  I am using Ubuntu 64 bit and gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5)

Comment: gcc. What `extern` means is a question about C, not about the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared `i` but haven't defined it, that's why the linker is complaining.

Comment: i=20 I have defined so I am not clear as why is it not taking that let me know if I missed some thing.

Comment: @Registered User : That's not definition. That is assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You declared i as extern. Removing this keyword fixes the issue, because extern means something which is defined in another module

Comment: actually I want to understand why is using extern in the above type of situation a problem.I am trying to improve upon my C skills hence please let me know. Thanks

Comment: @Registered user: because extern means something which is defined in another module. The linker tries to search for this variable in other modules but since you didn't include any other the linker doesn't find the variable and complains.